# Minimum crosses over N parallel lines

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations, backtracking

Let's say we have n disjoint horizontal parallel bars. Then we need to connect each pair of bars with a vertical line, so there are total `sum(n,...,1)` lines. If any of these connections between two bars crossed other bars p times, then we say the cost is p. The question is to find the minimum total cost for n bars.

```
n=1, p=0:     n=2, p=0:     n=3, p=0  n=4, p=0: 

                              ---        -----
                              | |        | | |
---          ---            --- |      --- | |
               |              | |      | | | |
               ---            ---      | --- |
                                       |   | |
                                       ------- 

n=6, p=3:
-------------
| |     | | | 
| ----- | | |
| | | | | | | 
| | | --- | |
| | | | | | | 
--*-*-- | | |
  | |   | | | 
  | ----*-- |
  | |   |   | 
  -----------

n=7, p=6:
---------------
| | |     | | | 
| --*---- | | |
| | | | | | | | 
| | | --*-- | |
| | | | | | | | 
| | --- | | | |
| | | | | | | | 
| | | --*-*-- |
| | | | | |   | 
--*-*---- |   |
  | |     |   | 
  -------------

n=8, p=11
-------------------
| | | |       | | | 
| --1-1------ | | |
| | | |     | | | | 
| | --2---- | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | 
| | | | | --1-- | |
| | | | | | | | | | 
| | | --1-- | | | |
| | | | |   | | | | 
| | | | ----1-1-- |
| | | | |   | |   | 
--1-1-1------ |   |
  | | |       |   | 
  -----------------
```

Any hints of how to find the patterns or logic behind it will be great.

Comment: It is worth to specify problem more clear, show a picture for better understanding and represent own efforts.

Comment: It's not clear how you want to achieve minimum cost, since the connections are given. Can you re-order the bars in the perpendicular direction?

Comment: the ```sum(n,...,1)``` also looks dubious (because equals ```(n(n+1)/2)```), all pairs of bars is ```C_n^2``` which is ```n(n-1)/2```

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework exercise to me. Recommended reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/9480133 and https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166

Comment: I think what OP is trying to ask is: How you can arrange N horizontal lines (of any length and start at any offset) such that when you draw vertical lines connecting each pair of line then it will result in minimum crossover. For example

N = 1, Cost --> 0
N = 2, Cost --> 0
N = 3, There can be three ways to arrange 3 parallel lines
https://imgur.com/a/SmsBmBL

Configuration 2 gives cost 0. So minimum cost is 0.

Similarly I tried manually calculating it. Starting with n = 1.
Seq: 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4

Comment: Maybe you could start by giving a brute-force implementation of this algorithm. So you transform the problem into a program that e.g. works on a (n * sum(n-1, ... 1)) array, draws "bars" of each lengths and position in that array, finds minimum cost lines for each pair, and calculates total costs. Based on that, you might find a faster solution.

Comment: Can you explain how you get 4 when n = 7?

Comment: I get 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 10, 20, 37, 56, 84, 120, ... is this correct?

Comment: Correct until 6. for n = 6, the best we can get is 3.

Comment: Can you explain how you use brutal force...? I can't even figure that out

Answer (score 3):

Here is an draft-solution solving the problem using Brute force **assuming an optimal solution for n bars can be found in a grid having n+1 columns only** (This assumptions seems wrong at least for n>=8. By changing parameters the search can be extended, worst Case is sum(n-1, ... 1), but this will further slow down search, mostly by adding redundant solutions).

The algorithm has exponential complexity and will only give results within useful time for very low numbers. As I said in the comments, this approach can be somewhat improved by reducing the search space allowing only combinations of bars that have sandclock shape (long bars outside, short bars inside, the outermost bars are longest, cover the same space, and all other bars can be placed inside the outermost columns). However so far I found no other useful property to use. Note some property might exist that only is true for some optimal solutions, e.g. that the center bar has lenght 2.

A better way might be to use exactly sum(n-1, ... 1) columns, with each connection having it's own column, the number of variants might actually be lower.

Whether a useful dynamic programming solution exists, I don't know.

```java
public class BarConnection {

    static class Bar {
        int start, end;
        private final int maxlength, minlength;

        Bar(int maxlength, int minlength) {
            this.maxlength = maxlength;
            this.minlength = minlength;
            reset();
        }

        public boolean next() {
            start++;
            if (start > 0) {
                return reset((end - start) + 2);
            }
            end++;
            return true;
        }

        public void reset() {
            reset(minlength);
        }

        public boolean reset(int length) {
            if (length > maxlength) {
                return false;
            }
            start = -length;
            end = 0;
            return true;
        }
    }

    static class Solution {
        private Bar[] bars;
        private int globalmin, globalmax, cost;

        Solution(int n) {
            bars = new Bar[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                bars[i] = new Bar(/* maxlength */ n, /* minlength */ 1);
            }
        }

        private boolean connect(final int maxcost) {
            cost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int sumcost = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < (bars.length - 1); i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < bars.length; j++) {
                    final int pairCost = minCostBetween(i, j);
                    if (pairCost == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    sumcost += pairCost;
                    if (sumcost > maxcost) {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
            cost = sumcost;
            return true;
        }

        boolean nextSolution(final int maxcost) {
            while (true) {
                while (bars[0].next()) {
                    if (connect(maxcost)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                bars[0].reset();
                for (int i = 1; i < bars.length; i++) {
                    if (bars[i].next()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (i == bars.length - 1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    bars[i].reset();
                }
                if (connect(maxcost)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        private int minCostBetween(final int i, final int j) {
            int minConnectionCost = -1;
            for (int k = Math.max(bars[i].start, bars[j].start); k <=
                    Math.min(bars[i].end, bars[j].end); k++) {
                // calculate cost for connecting at column k
                int newcost = 0;
                for (int l = i + 1; l < j; l++) {
                    final Bar midbar = bars[l];
                    if ((k >= midbar.start) && (k <= midbar.end)) {
                        newcost++;
                        if ((minConnectionCost >= 0) && (newcost >=
                                minConnectionCost)) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ((minConnectionCost < 0) || (newcost < minConnectionCost)) {
                    minConnectionCost = newcost;
                    if (newcost == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return minConnectionCost;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 6
        final Solution searchState = new Solution(n);
        int minCost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while(true) {
            if (!searchState.nextSolution(minCost - 1)) {
                break;
            }
            minCost = searchState.cost, minCost;
            if (minCost == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("n=" + n + ", p=" + minCost);
    }
}
```